# Xcode 4 - Adding the iOS developer library reference to Organizer - Documentation

Tags: ios, xcode

In Xcode 4, my Organizer - Documentation window doesn't appear to have the iOS documentation installed, only Mac OS X 10.6 Core Library and Xcode 4.0 Developer Library.

Does anyone know if it's possible to add it without re-installing the whole of Xcode 4? (which I really don't want to do...)

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Go to Xcode -> Preferences -> Documentation and click GET on the iOS 4.3 Documentation. In the iTunes-style status window, the download progress will be shown.

**As of the release of Xcode 4.2 with iOS 5:**

Go to Xcode -> Preferences -> Downloads -> (Tab) Documentation and click Install on the  documentation libraries you need. The download progress will be shown in that window for each documentation library you chose to install.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a lot, that's perfect. I didn't think of looking there.

Comment: I'm not sure why this wasn't installed when I updated to Xcode 4 through the iOS portal, thanks!